# how I use the QTextEdit in pyqt5 to show all style of the html (including the style of css)

Tags: python, html, css, pyqt, pyqt5

Python 3.6 PYQT 5.12.1

I am ready to show the style I need by pyqt5 and I knew that the QTextEdit in pyqt5 can display the html code pretty good (I have some experience in web development), so I decided to use html/css to show my style . However , it may have some problem in showing the code in css . What can I do to let it can show the css/javascript ? If it can‘t , can recommend other methods to modify the style?

It can show some style like  `width = "100" height = "100"` when I code it in the html but not css and some can't display like `border-radius:50%;`. It won't get any effect when I code the style in css . By the way , I've imported CSS code.
The CSS code do nothing in QTextEdit (but it is ok in html)

**.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class WINDOW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        w_width,w_height,w_x,w_y  = 700,640,700,200
        self.set_size_pos(w_width,w_height,w_x,w_y);
        self.set_message_textedit()
        self.message_textedit.setHtml(self.get_html())        
        self.show()

    def set_size_pos(self,width,height,x,y):
        '''
        set window's width , height and position
        '''
        self.resize(width,height)
        self.move(x,y)

    def set_message_textedit(self):
        self.message_textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.message_textedit.setFont(QFont("Microsoft YaHei",12))
        self.message_textedit.resize(680,420)
        self.message_textedit.move(10,50)
        self.message_textedit.setReadOnly(True)

    def get_html(self):
        html = ""
        with open("./chat-style/chat.html","r",encoding = "utf-8") as f:
            html = f.read()
        return html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = WINDOW()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lange="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./chat.css">
        <script src = "chat.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class = "tx" src="E:\study\assiataant\picture\icon.jpg">
        <div>Welcome ~ Don!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**.css**

```css
.tx
{        
    border-radius:50%;
    width:  30;
    height: 30;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTextEdit only supports CSS 2.1 as indicated by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#supported-css-selectors):

> All CSS 2.1 selector classes are supported except pseudo-class selectors such as :first-child, :visited and :hover.

But `border-radius` was introduced in CSS3. So you can not use it unfortunately. I recommend you read the following link so that you know the allowed tags.

Another alternative is to use QWebEngineView that supports these tags:

***.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        file = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 
            "chat-style/chat.html"
        )
        view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you do not have QWebEngineView installed, you must install it with the following command:

```
python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Comment: thanks , I will take some time to read it . What I want to do is insert a picture by html in QTextEdit and use CSS let it rounded  ， but it does't seem to work by this (not only border-radius but the height ="100" or others)
’‘’
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./chat.css">
‘’‘

Comment: @Don You could tell me the code you use. The image where is this respect to .py? Is it in the same folder or another?

Comment: the statement I use in .py is 
self.message_textedit.setHtml(self.get_html()),get_html() is my function to get the html code from the .html

Comment: @Don If you want help then provide a [mcve], with the information you provide I can not implement anything

Comment: @Don It seems that CSS 2.1 does not support setting width and height using style.

Comment: @Don QTextEdit has many limitations in handling modern HTML, an alternative is to use QWebEngineView